# automatic post-construction initialisation

Tags: c#, reflection

`virtual` methods should not be called in the constructor of a base class because the constructor of the derived class is not called and so all initialisation logic isn't invoked.

I want to know if there is a way to hook in there to automatically call a method after the object is completely constructed.
I do not want to push the responsibility of calling an initialise method onto the user.

Lets say I have the following

```
public abstract class Foo
{
  protected Foo()
  {
    ...
    AfterConstruction();
  }

  protected virtual void AfterConstruction(){}
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
  protected override void AfterConstruction()
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

I know this should not be done and I thought maybe one can get around this by using reflection to observe object construction and then hook after the construction is finished to call the function `AfterConstruction()`.
But I cannot find appropriate code to do so.

Thank you for your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

If I miss some important detail, do tell, but you have multiple options depending on when your class is considered fully initialized.
Also, "After Constructor" is the same as last line inside constructor (usually anyways), is there anything inside your logic to contradict that?

If full class initialization can be achieved inside the class you are making:
 1. Call it at the end of constructor or wherever your class is initialized.
 2. Call it in child class after base constructor. This will ensure base class is initialized.

If you cannot achieve a full class initialization inside your own classes, in other words, if your class is only considered initialized AFTER the user initialized some parameters - you have no choice but to leave at least 1 method call to the creator of your child class.

Default constructor of a base class will be called before child class constructor:
Simple code to test:

```
class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         new Bar();
     }
 }


class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Foo");
    }
}

class Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Bar");
    }
}
```

Output:

> MessageBox: "Foo"
>
> MessageBox: "Bar"

Comment: Actually I guess the important part is that the user may or may not implement the constructor of the derived class and may or may not implement the `AfterConstruction()` method. But still I need to call this method. This is because it is something like a contract that guarantees the inheritor that whatever s/he implements in the `AfterConstruction()` method it will be called after construction. To explain why I need the method would get off the topic, but if it is necessary I can update the question.

Comment: If i remember correctly default constructor (with no arguments) is always executed when child class is created. I'll test in a second.

Comment: Yeah, default constructor will be called, so you might want  to use a default constructor.

Comment: I know that but the problem lies elsewhere when the constructor of the base class is invoked the object is still not of the derived type still `Foo` (derived constructor not invoked yet) so when I call a virtual method in the base class constructor which is of type `Bar` then when you use `Bar`-members etc. they are not initialised, because as I said `Bar`-constructor has not been invoked yet and all `Bar`-state-information is ignored

I know how it works in case of inheritance:
base constructor -> special constructor -> more special constructor

but with methods is reversed:
most special ->..